# Slow Model!! Designed with ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, performance

I have designed a Model to assess flood vulnerability using ModelBuilder and some python scripts. The Model has overall 56 stages of process.

My problem is that when a user clicks on the model from the ArcToolbox, it takes a while to load the Dialog box.
Moreover, whenever the user clicks on a input box (in the dialog box) to define the path of the input source file, it takes a while to load the path!

The model runs without any noticeable delay or slow process and the SLOWNESS is only attributed to the first load of the model and defining the inputs.

What can I do to fasten the loading processes?

The model is fully offline (i.e. all files are on local drives) and uses the following tools:

Extract By Mask, Raster Calculator, Slope, Multiple ring buffer, Int, Raster to polygon, Update, Polygon to raster, Clip, Update, Select, Copy features, Add geometry attributes, Add field, Calculate field, , Add field, Calculate Field + 2 python scripts and a branching tool

updates:
[image]

[image]

Comment: By "fully offline" do you mean that all your data is on local drives?

Comment: Try to run some tiny model first.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap are you using?

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes I mean local files. And I am using ArcMAP Desktop 10.4

Comment: How many input and output parameters does the tool have?

Comment: There are 6 required inputs and 6 optional inputs. moreover a saving path should be assigned by the user. I will attach a photo of dialog box and the model

Comment: @FelixIP it runs fine with a small model, but idk what happens in this model

Comment: Are you writing temporary outputs to disk or are you using in-memory workspace?

Comment: A test: Open the [Generate Service Areas](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/generate-service-areas.htm) tool. Does it take a really long time to open? If so, it's probably the same issue. I remember at some point a change went in to speed up the opening of tools with a LOT of parameters. 12 total isn't a lot, but its a decent amount. The other test would be to hard code your parameters and NOT expose any of them except perhaps 1. Does it still take a long time to open?

Comment: @Aaron I'm not sure how can I answer you, i have not specified a workspace, but many outputs are marked as intermediate data. Does Specifying a workspace help the issue?

Comment: @KHibma I will let you know as soon as i test what you mentioned

Comment: Writing temporary data to the in-memory workspace accesses memory which is much faster than accessing disk space. More details here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm

Comment: @Aaron As I understand the problem, its slow to open the initial model; OP is not saying slow to run the model. in_memory would absolutely help speed up execution time. It shouldn't have any impact on tool open time.

Comment: This isn't a perfect solution, but consider porting the whole thing over to Python unless you want users to be able to access data from midway through the process.